# lenevo u41-70 (windows 10-64bit) i3(sshd to ssd replacement)

Tags: ssd

I want to upgrade my current sshd [(wd) model no -wd10521x] to a ssd ,but when i inquired it with lenevo customer care they said my laptop doesn't support ssd.
and when i see the hardware maintenance manual its clearly written there that it supports ssd (i think!).
[i am attaching hardware maintenance manual[1] for lenevo u41-70]so, does my laptop support ssd or not?

[i am attaching hardware maintenance manual[1] for lenevo u41-70]: https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/lenovo_s41-35_s41-70_s41-75_u41-70_hmm_201503.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If your computer has SATA connection for the sshd (most likely it has it), it shouldn't be a proble, your computer is compatible with ssd, Lenovo doesn't wwant you to open their product, that's it
Reading the user manual you attached there are some models of your computer' series that have ssd, so don't worry about it